# How do I align dollar amounts so cents match up in C++?

Tags: c++, text-alignment

My program executes just fine, but I was wondering how to align my output so cents line up rather than dollars.

We've only started class a couple weeks ago, so we haven't gone over this yet. My professor says it's okay for now if they don't align, I guess I'm just OCD about it. Plus, I think it looks a lot cleaner.

Also, if the bill is $38.40, would that be four significant figures? Sorry, I haven't taken math in a while. In my output, I'm getting up to five significant figures for some reason. The most I have is four. How would I fix this, using setprecision?

```
cout << "Bill \t \t   $  " << bill << endl;
cout << "Tax at 10.5% \t \t $"<<tax<< endl;
cout << "Sub-total \t \t $"<<subTotal<< endl;
cout << "Tip at 20% \t \t $"<<tip<< endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Total Bill \t \t \t $"<<totalBill<< endl;
```

As you see, I've been trying it using the tab escape. As a reply suggests, I should use setw?

**Edit for 9/10:**

I've gotten all my dollar amounts rounded to two decimals, except for the bill, and I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for all the info you've given me, but it's too advanced for what we're doing right now, so I've just aligned things manually. I still need to add setw and then fix everything once that's there. I'm just asking about why the bill is only three digits. It's probably something super simple that's going right over my head.

```
 // Declare variables
double bill, tax, subTotal, tip, totalBill;

// Variables
bill = 38.40;
tax = .105;
tip = .20;

// Calculate the tax
tax = bill * .105;

// Calculate sub-total of bill
subTotal = bill + tax;

// Calculate tip
tip = subTotal * .20;

// Calculate total amount of bill
totalBill = subTotal + tip;

cout << "Bill" "         $ " << setprecision(4) << bill << endl;
cout << "Tax at 10.5%" " $ " << setprecision(3) << tax << endl;
cout << "Sub-total" "    $ " << setprecision(4) << subTotal << endl;
cout << "Tip at 20%" "   $ " << setprecision(3) << tip << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Total Bill" "   $ " << setprecision(4) << totalBill << endl;
```

**Edit:** I "fixed" it. All is good now.

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow.com must include all complete and pertinent question in the message itself, instead of a link to some external web site that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. You need to edit your question, remove that link, and replace it with the pertinent information. Furthermore, questions of the form "how do I change my code to do X instead" must obviously show the code, unless you're willing to wait until all our psychics return from their lunch break, and are able to look at your code in order that we can figure out what to change about it.

Comment: Minus the unneeded sarcasm, thanks. I'm new and I tried to do it without the link, but it wouldn't let me. I'll edit it. Also, I didn't think it was necessary to have the code since it executed just fine, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I love your comment.  Too often the nasty "this question is low quality and should be closed" words appear.  Instead you made me smile.

Comment: @TrevorHickey  You were a lot of help and was wondering if you could help with another quick question. I've edited my post to add that I've manually aligned everything (I still need to add setw) and got my dollar amounts rounded except for the bill. I don't understand why it's only three digits. Changing setprecision doesn't do anything.

Comment: @deW1 You were help too, thanks. The response above is for you as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're printing money,  I recommend you look at C++'s [money I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money).
`std::put_money` will ensure you are international compliant and printing with correct rounding/precision.

Set the locale of `std::cout` for USD.
`std::showbase` will decide whether to print the `$`.

```
  //settings for printing as USD
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
  std::cout << std::showbase;
```

---

Use [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [std::left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) for formatting.
Here is an example of printing your data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>  

//row data from example
struct Row{
  std::string description;
  float amount;
};

//function for printing a row
void Print(Row row);

int main(){

  //example rows
  Row a{"Bill",3840};
  Row b{"Tax at 10.5%",403};
  Row c{"Sub-total",4243};
  Row d{"Tip at 20%",848};
  Row e{"Total Bill",5091};

  //settings for printing as USD
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
  std::cout << std::showbase;

  //format printing
  Print(a);
  Print(b);
  Print(c);
  Print(d);
  std::cout << '\n';
  Print(e);
}

void Print(Row row){
  static const int COLUMN_WIDTH{14};
  std::cout << std::setw(COLUMN_WIDTH) << std::left << row.description;
  std::cout << " " << std::right << std::put_money(row.amount) << '\n';
}
```

**result:**

```
Bill           $38.40
Tax at 10.5%   $4.03
Sub-total      $42.43
Tip at 20%     $8.48

Total Bill     $50.91
```

Comment: While I appreciate all that information, it's a little advanced for what I need to do. We haven't covered a lot of what you've given, so I doubt we need it. I can use setprecision to get the number of significant figures to where I need them to be, I was just wondering why it printed out five when there's only a max of four being used. I only declared up to four sig. figs. Thanks for the setw info. I just looked in our book and it was a lot more simplified. I still need to read through it a couple more times for it to make sense.

Comment: @Alexa No problem.  I wanted to leave a descriptive answer on how it ought to be done for production code.  It may very well be overkill for a school assignment.

Comment: Yeah, it's still nice to know for future use. I can definitely come back to this once we get that far.

Comment: @Alexa I wrote a little simpler version of this, I wasn't going to share it but maybe that helps clarify some things for you? The relevant part is the output http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2007dfd9af340f87 btw. +1 Trevor ty for ruining my answer :p

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to use [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/).

```
cout<<setw(5)<<4.55<<endl;
cout<<setw(5)<<44.55<<endl;

output:
 4.55
44.55
```

Update:
as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, the `<<` operator resets the width, hence  the code is updated to show it should be repeated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look in our book to see how it's used. I only looked up setprecision.

Comment: You'd still have alignment problems if you needed a width of 10, say.  The first number would have that width; the second would not.  It happens to work OK with the numbers chosen here, but change 44.55 to -44.55 or 444.55 and you will have alignment problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you're right, missed the second setw!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << "Bill";
std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << bill << std::endl;

std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::left << "Tax @ 10.5%";
std::cout << std::setw(15) << std::right << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << tax << std::endl;
```

This sets the width of the output for each "column" to 15 characters so you don't have to rely on tabs. All of the the "labels" will be left justified, and all of the prices will be right justified and printed to 2 decimal places. This is a bit more robust than relying on tabs, where you don't have control as to how many characters are used. You can't do proper justification with tabs.